# Send client certificate to Server in Tcl

Tags: ssl-certificate, tcl

Currently my application (in C) authenticates to a web server using an SSL certificate. I'm now moving most of the funcitions (if not all) to Tcl.

I couldn't find any tutorial or example on how to do it (I'd prefere to use Tcl ::http:: but TclCurl would be fine).

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use https with tcl you usually use the [`tls`](http://tls.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tls/tls/tls.htm?revision=HEAD) package. The man page for the [http package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/http.htm#M44) gives you an example how to do that:

```
package require http
package require tls

::http::register https 443 ::tls::socket

set token [::http::geturl https://my.secure.site/]
```

If you read the documentation of the [tls](http://tls.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tls/tls/tls.htm?revision=HEAD#tls%3a%3aimport) package for `tls::socket`, you find that there are some options to pass client certificates. Combining that gives you:

```
::http::register https 443 [list ::tls::socket \
        -cafile caPublic.pem -certfile client.pem]
```

You might have to specify the `-password` callback parameter if the certificate file is protected by a password.

Note that this solution uses the client certificate for each https (regardless of the target) request from your application.

**Edit**: As Donal suggested, it might be better to use `tls::init` than to specify it with `::http::register`.
An example:

```
package require http
package require tls

::http::register https 443 ::tls::socket

proc ::get_cert_pass {} {
     return "passw0rd"
}

# Add the options here
::tls::init -cafile caPublic.pem -certfile client.pem -password ::get_cert_pass
set tok [::http::geturl https://my.secure.site/]
```

To do a request, always use the last 2 line then.

Comment: IIRC, you handle passwords by creating a command called `::tls::password` ([see example](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2630#pagetocf176242a)) that returns the relevant password. (No, I don't know what the formal arguments should be.)

Answer (score 4):

Johannes's answer is right, except if you want to provide different identities to different sites. In that case you use `tls::init`, which allows you to set default TLS-related options to `tls::socket` prior to that command being called.

```
package require http
package require tls
http::register https 443 ::tls::socket

# Where is our identity?
tls::init -keyfile "my_key.p12" -cafile "the_server_id.pem"

# Now, how to provide the password (don't know what the arguments are)
proc tls::password args {
    return "the_pass";  # Return whatever the password is
}

# Do the secure connection
set token [http::geturl https://my.secure.site/]

# Disable the key
tls::init -keyfile {}
```

Note that the way of providing the password *is* bizarre, and I know for sure that this mechanism isn't going to be nice when doing asynchronous connections. (There's a standing Feature Request for improving the integration between the http and tls packages…)

Comment: according to the tls documentation, the use of `tls::password` is not recommended. Better use the `-password` (default IS `tls::password`) parameter to specify the callback. No arguments are appended. See the [Callback Section](http://tls.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tls/tls/tls.htm?revision=HEAD#CALLBACK%20OPTIONS) of the documentation.

Comment: @Johannes It seems that that's only in some versions of the documentation (not including the [version](http://www.sensus.org/tcl/tls.htm) I looked at). Ick.